# MySQL : Convert year, week & day values to date

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying to convert 3 separated fields (year,week & day) to a date field.
Here are some examples values :

Year : something classic like 2012 - Week : from 1 to 52 - Day : from 1 to 7

I really have no idea how I could convert this... thanks for help !

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read the [site guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question, and edit your question to provide more information about how you're trying to do the conversion.  Are you using Javascript, PHP, a query, something else?

Comment: My mistake. Actually I'm upgrading a MySQL database, so all I need are SQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chekout this [date_format](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp). '%U' or '%u' parameters solve your problem for week and '%w' solve day too;